# why does my sites IIS Hostname load the site, but variants do not work

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, server

We have a site in iis, let's call it example.com. I've added bindings for an ip address we secured, and it happily takes it, and loads the site when using "http://example.com" or it's https counterpart (wildcard ssl cert also used). Whenever I try to add bindings for "www.example.com", or any other type of host name, like dev.example.com, anything other than the one that matches the site name in iis, the browser will simply throw a 404 with no additional information. I'm really at a loss on this one, I've added the hostnames that don't load to the hosts file as well, stopped all sites to verify nothing else is picking up the request somehow, etc. and still no luck.

This is the latest IIS version, for what it's worth.

Comment: example.com and www.example.com should belong to different tier domain. Have you registered DNS for it? Besides, could you post your IIS binding configuration? If the DNS has been registered, could you enable failed request tracing and compare the request from example.com and www.example.com.

Comment: @JokiesDing Can you explain what you mean by "Different tier domain"? I enabled tracing and it gives a not found on "OUTPUT_CACHE_LOOKUP_END".

Comment: Show your site bindings please. They decide what URLs you might use in a web browser to access the site, so wrong bindings can easily lead to 404s for certain URLs. The background information can be found in https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: @TrevorHart It just means httpcache module end. Did you see anything in ErrorCode field and what's the substatus code? it would looks likeHttpStatus="404", HttpReason="Not Found", HttpSubStatus=" 4", ErrorCode=".........". Please ensure FRT is logging the correct request.

Comment: @JokiesDing The substatus is 0. I'm definitely looking at the correct log, I watch it generate as I make the request that fails.

Comment: It sounds like real 404 error. Do you have URL rewrite installed?